# JS сумирование чисел

Tags: javascript

```js
var getNum = document.getElementById('get_num');
var addTime = document.getElementById('add');
var totalTime = document.getElementById("total_time");
var addSpan = document.getElementById('add_span');
var spanCount = document.querySelectorAll('.total-time > span');
addTime.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var currentTime = getNum.value;
  if (currentTime != "") {
    console.log(totalTime.innerHTML);
    totalTime.innerHTML = totalTime.innerHTML + currentTime;
    createTimeBlock(currentTime);
    getNum.value = "";
  } else {
    console.log(1212);
  }



}, false);


function createTimeBlock(currentTime) {
  var newSpan = document.createElement('span');
  newSpan.innerHTML = currentTime;
  addSpan.appendChild(newSpan);
  // for(let i = 0; i < spanCount.length; i++){
  //  console.log(spanCount[i]);
  // }
}
```

```css
.btn {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.total-time span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: skyblue;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.total-time span:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 2px;
  top: 30px;
  left: 13px;
}

.total-time span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 52px;
  top: 38px;
  right: 15px;
}

.total-time span:first-child:after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>Write time: <input type="text" id="get_num" maxlength="3">
  <div id="add" class="btn">Add</div>
</div>
<div>TOTAL TIME: <span id="total_time">0</span></div>
<div id="add_span" class="total-time"></div>
```

Когда ввожу число в поле и нажимаю на кнопку добавить, все работает хорошо. Но когда ввожу и добавляю снова, сумма в TOTAL TIME не суммируется.

Подскажите, что делаю не так?

Здесь [код на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/webEugene29/74e4s9fk/).

Comment: Вы суммируете строки вместо чисел, сделайте так : `totalTime.innerHTML = +totalTime.innerHTML + +currentTime;`

Comment: Перенесите код прямо в текст вопроса

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте новую переменную для аккумулирования суммы времени, к примеру:

```
var sumTime = 0;
```

Замените ваш код

```
totalTime.innerHTML = totalTime.innerHTML + currentTime;
```

на

```
sumTime += parseInt(currentTime);
```

Выводите переменную с суммой аккумулированного времени

```
totalTime.innerHTML = sumTime;
```

Answer (score -2):

пояснения в комментарии в js

```js
var getNum = document.getElementById('get_num');
var addTime = document.getElementById('add');
var totalTime = document.getElementById("total_time");
var addSpan = document.getElementById('add_span');
var spanCount = document.querySelectorAll('.total-time > span');
addTime.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var currentTime = getNum.value;
  if (currentTime != "" && !isNaN(currentTime)) {
    /*умножение на единицу и преобразовываем стоку в число*/
    totalTime.innerHTML = totalTime.innerHTML * 1 + currentTime * 1;
    createTimeBlock(currentTime);
    getNum.value = "";
  } else {
    alert('Введите число');
    getNum.value = "";
  }
}, false);


function createTimeBlock(currentTime) {
  var newSpan = document.createElement('span');
  newSpan.innerHTML = currentTime;
  addSpan.appendChild(newSpan);
  // for(let i = 0; i < spanCount.length; i++){
  //  console.log(spanCount[i]);
  // }
}
```

```css
.btn {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.total-time span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: skyblue;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.total-time span:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 2px;
  top: 30px;
  left: 13px;
}

.total-time span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 52px;
  top: 38px;
  right: 15px;
}

.total-time span:first-child:after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>Write time: <input type="text" id="get_num" maxlength="3">
  <div id="add" class="btn">Add</div>
</div>
<div>TOTAL TIME: <span id="total_time">0</span></div>
<div id="add_span" class="total-time"></div>
```

Comment: Интересно, кто минусует рабочий ответ...